# keyboard hiding textfields in tableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a tableViewController having 2 sections ....
1st section has 7 rows & 2nd section has 2 rows.
So when i edit in textfields of 2nd section keyboard hides these field so how i will handle 
keyboard for these fields only.(i am using tableviewController which has default scrolling).
I am new to objective -C.....Your help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On tapping any cell with text field, you can navigate to another view with only a text field, keyboard and Done and Cancel buttons. this feels pretty neat. You can see this in many of apple's iphone apps as well... e.g. Go to iPhone Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Signature.

EDIT: since you cant use the standard way you can move the complete view up with following code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
CGPoint currentCenter = [self.view center];
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(currentCenter.x, currentCenter.y - 150);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[self.view setCenter:newCenter];
[UIView commitAnimations];
return YES;
}
```

change the animation duration and the change in position of the center (150) in this code according to your requirements. I have assumed that your view controller is the delegate for your textfield. 
To bring the view back to it's original position, use same code but add to center.y in textFieldShouldReturn or textFieldShouldEndEditing etc

```
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(currentCenter.x, currentCenter.y - 150);
```

P.S. : I'm still not sure you should be using this second approach.

Comment: Sorry...But this is not any Solution.
How i have to meet the Requirements...i can't do this.

Comment: well, in that case, you can also move up your entire view with animation in sync with the keyboard, but i'm not sure it'll look good.

Comment: But i have been told to do so.
so any help for this one.